# Latex table centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm wondering how could I center text in table vertically and horizontally?

I've seen several manuals and answred questions, but there are many way to create a table and as I'm a begginer in Tex I can't find any sollutions.

Thanks!!!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[] 
{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}                                           
\usepackage[nohyperlinks]{acronym}                      
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


 \begin{document}

 \begin {table}
   \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ | p{10cm} | c | c |}
       \hline
       Scenario & A & B \\ \hline
       Subscenario & A.1 & B.1 \\ \hline
       Number of registered individuals/impostors & 25/65 & 23/14 \\ \hline
       Number of face images    of registered individuals/impostors & 6549/223 &     1082/20182 \\ \hline
    Total number of face images per scenario registered individuals/impostors & 619/223  & 1082/41\\ \hline
    Total number of face images registered individuals/impostors &  \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{ 1701/264 } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description of the IFaViD's image test set}
\label{IFaViD_img}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Vertical centering of a tabular environment is possible with `text \vfill  \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \vfill text ` for explample, but have no sense (and do not work) inside a float `table` so it is no clear what is really your problem. Please, explain clearly what you are trying with respect you MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `m` column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | m{10cm} | c | c |}
    \hline
    Scenario & A & B \\ \hline
    Subscenario & A.1 & B.1 \\ \hline
    Number of registered individuals/impostors & 25/65 & 23/14 \\ \hline
    Number of face images   of registered individuals/impostors & 6549/223 & 1082/20182 \\ \hline
    Total number of face images per scenario registered individuals/impostors & 619/223  & 1082/41\\ \hline
    Total number of face images registered individuals/impostors &  \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{ 1701/264 } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description of the IFaViD's image test set}
\label{IFaViD_img}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]